# passing the intent of first activity to the third activity

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

I am creating an application that prompts the user for information, with different activities for each question. I need to pass the values from the first, second, and third activities to the fourth activity, which displays all the inputted information. Currently, I only know how to pass the value from the first to the second activity, and am unsure how to pass all activity data to the final activity.

here's my code for my first activity

```
    String firstname = edt_FN.getText().toString();
    String lastname = edt_LN.getText().toString();
    String email = edt_EM.getText().toString();
    String phone = edt_phone.getText().toString();
    String height = edt_H.getText().toString();
    String weight = edt_W.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(PersonalBackground.this, next.class);
    i.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
    i.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
    i.putExtra("email", email);
    i.putExtra("phone", phone);
    i.putExtra("height", height);
    i.putExtra("weight", weight); 
    startActivity(i);
```

this is the code in my third activity

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String firstname = i.getStringExtra("firstname");
    String lastname = i.getStringExtra("lastname");
    String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
    String phone = i.getStringExtra("phone");
    String height = i.getStringExtra("height");
    String weight = i.getStringExtra("weight");
```

and to here's my textview to view the value of edittext in intent

```
    op_name.setText("Name: " + firstname + lastname);
    op_email.setText("Email: " + email);
    op_gender.setText("Gender: " + Male + Female);
    op_phone.setText("Phone no.: " + phone);
    op_height.setText("Height: " + height);
    op_weight.setText("Weight: " + weight);
```

i want to know how can i pass the value of intent of first activity to the third activity. i dont know if my code is right thats why i get i null output in my textview.